# How to insert new row for a particular column without overwritting previous data using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am doing a simple courier tracking project where I have two tables named `TrackingStatus` and `ParcelTracking`.

`ParcelTracking` table has `Tracking_ID` as a primary key and `TrackingStatus_ID` as a foreign key which is a primary key of `TrackingStatus` table.

Each time status of courier changes, I want to add new `TrackingStatus_ID`, so that I can retrieve all the previous status for that particular `Tracking_ID`.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: you can use normal update API?

Comment: which API should i  have to use Amer sir?

Comment: Simple retrieve the the object you want to update, then close the session to deattach( not nessecary if no much processing is happening) then use session.SaveOrUpdate(deattachedObject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've understood, this is less a problem with "updating" but more a problem with the layout of your schema and models. You're getting your columns a little mixed up by the looks of it.

By what you've said in the question it seems like you're doing this:

```
| TrakingStatus |        | ParcelTracking   |
|---------------|        |------------------|
| Id            |        | TrackingId       |
| ...           |--------| TrackingStatusId |
|               |        | ...              |
```

So what it seems like is that if a courier changes then you want to add a new `TrackingStatusId` which I'm guessing is that you want to create a new record in the `TrackingStatus` table and then reference that in the `ParcelTracking` table. You should use a [`OneToMany`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html) relationship here with a another table that allows you to reference the rows in `TrackingStatus` for a single Parcel in `ParcelTracking` and you'll have something like:

```
| TrakingStatus |          | ParcelStatuses  |              | ParcelTracking   |
|---------------|          |-----------------|              |------------------|
| Id            | -------- | TrackingId      | *-----------1| TrackingId       |
| ...           |          | TrackingStatusId|              | ...              |
```

This way, when a courier changes you don't need overwrite the existing `TrackingStatusId` value, you can simply create another record and link it with the same `ParcelTracking` object.

Comment: In this project i want to add the new status if courier changes rather than updating the status....I am stuck with this problem for about 2 days.Can you suggest me on this problem